# What would be the best practice to store multiple 2 digit dataset in MySql server

Tags: mysql, dataset

Let say i want to store several dataset ie

78 94 33 22 14 55 18 10 11

44 59 69 79 39 49 29 19 39

And later on i would like to be able run queries that will determine the frequency of certain number. What would be the best way to this? What would be table structure to make a fast query.

Please be specific as you can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the counts, you can run a query such as:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) from table_of_values GROUP BY value
```

Placing an index on the single integer value column is pretty much all you can do to speed that up.

You could of course also just keep a table with every two-digit value and a count.  You will have to pre-fill the table with zero counts for every value.

Then increment the count instead of inserting:

```
UPDATE table_of_values SET count = count + 1 WHERE value = (whatever)
```

Comment: How about storing all of them on the same table but in separate fields? so each value ie"44" would be in a seperate field ?

Comment: Why not. There are only 100 two-digit values. A 100-column table is not that big a deal. 

But lets say you are taking updates from a large number of updaters. Multiple rows will probably allow parallelism, because each row can be locked/updated separately.